# Question about inserting Users/Members into a database table!

Tags: asp.net, sql, ado.net

My registration form has got a CreateUserWizard. I used its event that is fired after the user is created.

Then I obtain the users identity and key. In the last line, I send the unique key to a function inside a class that should insert the key into the Users table (the field is a primary key and is unique).

```
public partial class Registration : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void CreateUserWizard1_CreatedUser(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MembershipUser CurrentUser = Membership.GetUser(User.Identity.Name);
        int i =(int) CurrentUser.ProviderUserKey;
        RegisterAdo.InsertUsers(i);
    }
}
```

Below, I execute the query with the value that I passed and insert the user into a database

```
class RegisterAdo
{
    public static void InsertUsers(int UsersIDentity)
    {
        string myConnectionString = WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["YourGuruDB"].ConnectionString;
        SqlConnection sqlConnect = new SqlConnection(myConnectionString);
        SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand(RegisterAdo.insertCommand(UsersIDentity), sqlConnect);
        try
        {
            sqlConnect.Open();
            sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        catch (Exception x)
        {

        }
        finally
        {
            sqlConnect.Close();
        }
    }

public static String insertCommand(int UsersIdentityToinsert)
{
    string insertCommand="INSERT INTO Users(";
    insertCommand += "UserID)";
    insertCommand += "VALUES('";
    insertCommand += UsersIdentityToinsert+"')";

    return insertCommand;
}
```

My question is whether it is the best way to insert `UserID` into a table, and whether I do it right at all. I need the `UserID` to be unique, and the whole command executed with no fail...(just after the user was created and the whole `UserCreateUser` finished validating the user!!!

Answer (score 2):

I would change two things mainly:

1. don't concatenate together your SQL statement - this opens doors to SQL injection attacks. Use parametrized queries instead - they are both safer, and they perform better (since only a single copy of the query's execution plan needs to be created and cached and will be reused over and over again)
2. put your `SqlConnection` and `SqlCommand` objects into `using` blocks so that they'll be automatically freed / disposed when the using blocks ends (and you can save yourself the `finally` block of the `try...catch` construct, too!).

So my code would look like this

```
    public static void InsertUsers(int UsersIDentity)
    {
        string myConnectionString = WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["YourGuruDB"].ConnectionString;

        string insertStmt =
           "INSERT INTO dbo.Users(UserID) VALUES(@UserID)";

        using(SqlConnection _con = new SqlConnection(myConnectionString))
        using(SqlCommand _cmd = new SqlCommand(insertStmt, sqlConnect))
        {
           _cmd.Parameters.Add("@UserID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = UsersIDentity;

          try
          {
              _con.Open();
              _cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
              _con.Close();
          }
          catch (Exception x)
          {
               // do something if error occurs
          }
      }
```